# Improving Time Efficiency in List Removal

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

What is a faster way to "remove" items I have already appended to my sequence so I don't come across them again? In my actual code I have much larger sequences of words, and consequently using `.remove(word)` is being very costly in time.

My current ideas:

- store the words in a heapq, instead of a list, and order them by the heuristic I am using. (the problem here is that I need to update the heuristic value after removing a word from the sequence, thus I don't believe its assisting in time complexity)
- use a hash map to check if words are in the sequence or not. How would time complexity be in this case?

I have the following code (I have used `random.choice` for simplicity, as I actually am using a heuristic to select my next word):

```
import random
d = {'b': ['bob', 'bun', 'bom'], 'd': ['dob', 'don'], 'm': ['mox']}

print(d)
seq = []
current = 'bob'
seq.append(current)
d[current[:1]].remove(current)
while current[-1:] in d and d[current[-1:]]:
    next_ = random.choice(d[current[-1:]])
    current = next_
    seq.append(current)
    d[current[:1]].remove(current)

print(d)
print(seq)
```

Example output:

```
{'b': ['bob', 'bun', 'bom'], 'd': ['dob', 'don'], 'm': ['mox']}
{'b': ['bun'], 'd': ['dob', 'don'], 'm': []}
['bob', 'bom', 'mox']
```

Comment: Use sets instead of lists?

Comment: Would you mind explaining the benefit of sets over lists? I understand reading is faster, though how would it help with "marking"/removing the items I have already used?

Comment: Removing elements from a list is O(n), while removing elements from a set is O(1). https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: `list` is an *ordered* collection. This is costly when doing remove (order must be kept). Do you need that order? It seems like a `dict` from the word to its heuristic value is a good choice of data structure here.

Comment: So simply using `d = {'b': ('bob', 'bun', 'bom')` instead should help a lot?

Comment: They are also libraries such as numpy that create faster data types and data that are specialised for certain tasks if an even faster solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is required if you want to keep the list intact but the order of the items does not matter. If you don't need to keep the list with all its item, It would be simpler to swap the item to remove with the last item `L[-1], L[idx] = L[idx], L[-1]` and call `L.pop()`.

---

Don't actually remove anything. Keep an count for each list and swap that element with the one to remove and reduce the count:

so `[0, []]` is the empty list and `[3, [1,2,3]]` is the list before removing `1` and `[2, [3,2,1]]` is the list after.

This makes removing items effectively the same as a Knuth shuffle step. Then to pick a random item you generate a number between 0 and the remaining count and then swap that index with the item at the remaining count minus 1.

To generate one: `[len(L)+1, L]`

To pick a random item:

```
remaining_count, L = cL
idx = random.randrange(0, remaining_count)
value = L[idx]
L[remaining_count - 1], L[idx] = L[idx], L[remaining_count - 1]
cL[0] = remaining_count - 1
```

random.randrange will raise ValueError when `remaining_count` is `-1` when the list has been depleted.

The result is the removal of items in O(1) time. And you can restore the lists to their original items although in shuffled order also in O(1) by `cL[0] = len(cL[1])`.

Should you need to trim off the removed elements this can be done with a single:

```
del cL[1][cL[0]-1:]
```

Which removes the elements after the remaining_count minus 1 and as this operation occurs at the end of the list its cost is low.

Comment: This is an awesome idea, however for my circumstances as I stated above, I am using a heuristic to select the words I will choose next. This however would work the same right? I can for loop until L and then select my index to use for value. Which would just save me time on removing which is worth it!